# VS Code annoying vertical lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

What is causing the vertical lines in this image?

Every file I edit has them.

Sometimes they disappear, but then they come back.

I am using VS Code `v1.66.1`

###### Here is an image of the lines:

[image: The lines]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, there are 6 settings that have to do with 2 features that sort of overlap each other. VS Code originally only supported standard indent guide highlighting, then they added a feature called colorized bracket pairs. VS Code releases monthly updates 11x times a year. The month, after `bracketColorizationPairs` was initially released, VS Code added more to `bracketPariColorization`, which included vertical and horizontal lines. Those lines are more configurable than indent guides, and can render in hard to get situations indent-guides was not able to. Also, they render horizontal, under the line of code that starts a block.

When both indent guides and bracketPairColorization lines are configured to both render, the bracketPairColorization gets priority over the older indent-guides feature.

To avoid all the confusion, add the settings below to your `settings.json` file, the completely restart your editor. It should solve the problem. Let me know the result.

```
{
    "editor.guides.highlightActiveIndentation": false,
    "editor.guides.indentation": false,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal": "false",
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "false",
    "editor.guides.highlightActiveBracketPair": false,
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType": false
}
```

Adding the settings displayed above will turn off the "bright annoying lines in VS Code" which are officially called: **Colorized Bracket Pairs**. Coloring the brackets, and bracket guides, is a bit beyond the scope of this Q&A, consequently, I won't explain how to change the colors, but I will create an active link [around this text your reading, that when clicked, will take you to an answer that explains coloring the guides and brackets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71675335/colourized-brackets-how-to-disable/71686132#71686132)

Comment: manual editing of the settings file and adding all of these to the end of file (+ removing the already existing lines) it's seems works.

Comment: also enabled the "editor.guides.highlightActiveBracketPair": true settings and this solution still work after restart, Thank you !

Comment: YW, and yeah, you will want to custom edit the settings. The features that the toggle **(_`ON`_ & _`OFF`_)** are extremely nice features. Also, you can set the bracket pairs like this:  `"editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active"`. This is what I do, rather than just setting it to a state of (OFF **=** `false` **|** ON **=** `true`)  you can set it so that they are off through the whole file, except for the one where you are actively working. You can also customize the color that they are highlight as too.

Comment: [This Q&A is another one I answered that touches on most of the same settings I mentioned in the answer to your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71675335/colourized-brackets-how-to-disable/71686132#71686132) The person was asking to turn of the color for His/Her brackets rather than the highlighting of the indent guides.  `workbench.colorCustomization` setting. In this answer I explain how to change the color of the bracket pairs, which will also change the indent guides, if your interested in how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the menu Code->Preference->Settings and search for "renderIndentGuides". The complete setting should appear as:

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
```

Change it to false.

UPDATE:

Keys had changed since v1.61 - on later version set the following instead:

```
"editor.guides.indentation": false
```

Comment: dont't work, already set to false :(

Comment: There can be 2 places where it has "editor.rulers" in the settings.json. Make both empty "editor.rulers": []. And restart VSC and try again

Comment: I guess this is BUG, The lines can be delete only if I make a TOGGLE on the "FOLDER" editor.guides.highlightActiveIndentation, no matter if turning ON or Off if make a toggle the lines disapearing, if toggling in the USER or Workspace no effect

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: all time need to toggle this settings to delete the lines after restarting the editor :(

Comment: As you mentioned it seems to be a VSC bug :/