# vscode bracket pairs changed colors with v1.67

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying out Swagger for Go. But somehow in Visual Studio Code it changed the colors.

[image: Weird looking code colors]

Before I installed Swagger the braces and brackets were not pink, yellow or blue.
I tried already uninstalling Swagger and Vscode but this didn't help. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm using this golang implementation of Swagger: https://goswagger.io/

Comment: I edited the title to make it easier for others to find (and since it isn't because of go or swagger).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable colorized brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71675335/how-to-disable-colorized-brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related to GO or any framework

Seems like you have mistakenly installed the vs-code extension "bracket-pair-colorizer-2"

Uninstall or disable the extension and the bracket colorization will be gone.

But, personally, i prefer using the bracket colorization as it helps to detect the start and end of the content inside a function

Comment: The installed extensions don't show "bracket-pair-colorizer-2". But there is in the settings an Option "Bracket Pair Colorization" when I turn this off the "problem" is solved :) Thanks! According to the documentation the "bracket-pair-colorizer-2" extension is now deprecated and has become a native feature in VSCode. Still wondering how it got activated.

Comment: @TheQuestioner, they made this third party extension first class at some point and build it into the vscode itself.

Answer (score 48):

v1.67 of vscode made colorization of matching brackets the default, see [Enable bracket pair colorization by default](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/9898ceaee26b8ea5172754e6dd3e042da0928191).  So it was just updating vscode to v1.67 that made the change for you.

`Editor > Bracket Pair Colorization: Enabled` the new default is `enabled`

Uncheck the box to disable it.

[v1.67 Release Notes: Bracket Pair colorization Enabled by Default](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_bracket-pair-colorization-enabled-by-default):

> Bracket pair colorization can also be disabled just for specific
> languages:

```
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false
}
```

Comment: If you want to disable for all the programming languages you can do:
Ctrl+Shift+P, search for `settings.json` and copy paste: `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false,` and that's it!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to turn it off.

On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
Then untick "Bracket Pair Colorization"

I've turned it off. The colours place emphasis on parts of the code I have little interest and I find my eyes constantly wondering back to it.